# Passive perfect tense.. Do both sentences have the same meaning?

Tags: passive-voice, perfect-constructions

- Older versions of Google Chrome have been detected multiple vulnerabilities.
- Multiple Vulnerabilities have been detected in old version of Chrome.

Do both sentences have the same meaning?

Comment: No. In your first sentence Chrome has found vulnerabilities somewhere else. In your second, Chrome _itself_ has vulnerabilities. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I edited. Could you please check it right now. 

Second one is correct. I put second tense on google translate. It generate exactly what i want. But when i translate from my mother tongue, Google translate generate first sentence.

Comment: OK. The second sentence is perfect. There are two other word-orders possible, but they are not as good: "Older versions of Google Chrome _with_ multiple vulnerabilities have been detected" and "Older versions of Google Chrome have been detected _with_ multiple vulnerabilities." BOTH of these suggest that older versions of Chrome have been detected, especially the last one. So I urge you to use your own second sentence! [Also, decide whether it's "old" or "older"!]

Comment: The first sentence doesn't work in English - it doesn't 'mean' anything, because there is nothing to link _multiple vulnerabilities_ with the rest of the sentence.